# node-kafka pause() method on consumer. Any working version?

Tags: node.js, apache-kafka

I can't make following code to work:

```
"use strict";

let kafka = require('kafka-node');
var conf = require('./providers/Config');

let client = new kafka.Client(conf.kafka.connectionString, conf.kafka.clientName);
let consumer = new kafka.HighLevelConsumer(client, [ { topic: conf.kafka.readTopic } ], { groupId: conf.kafka.clientName, paused: true });

let threads = 0;

consumer.on('message', function(message) {
    threads++;

    if (threads > 10) consumer.pause();

    if (threads > 50) process.exit(1);

    console.log(threads + " >>> " + message.value);
});

consumer.resume();
```

I see 50 messages in console and process exits by termination statement.

What I'm trying to understand, is that is it my code broken or package broken? Or maybe I'm just doing something wrong? Does anyone was able to make kafka consumer work with pause/resume? I tried several versions of kafka-node, but all of them behave same way. Thanks!

Comment: Currently I'm using kafka_2.11-0.8.2.1 and node-kafka 0.3.2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are already using `pause` and `resume` in your code, so obviously they work. ;)

It's because `pause` doesn't pause the consumption of messages. It pauses the fetching of messages. I'm guessing you already fetched the first 50 in one throw before you receive the first message and call `pause`.

For kicks, I just tested `pause()` and `resume()` in the Node REPL and they work as expected:

```
var kafka = require('kafka-node');
var client = new kafka.Client('localhost:2181');
var consumer = new kafka.HighLevelConsumer(client, [{topic: 'MyTest'}]);
consumer.on('message', (msg) => { console.log(JSON.stringify(msg)) });
```

Then I go into another window and run:

```
 bin/kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list localhost:9092 --topic MyTest
```

And type some stuff, and it shows up in the first window. Then in the first window, I type: `consumer.pause();` And type some more in the second window. Nothing appears in the first window. Then I run `consumer.resume()`in the first window, and the delayed messages appear.

BTW, you should be able to play with the Kafka config property `fetch.message.max.bytes` and control how many messages can be fetched at one time. For example, if you had fixed-width messages of 500 bytes, set `fetch.message.max.bytes` to something less than 1000 (but greater than 500!) to only receive a single message per fetch. But note that this might not fix the problem entirely -- I am fairly new to Node, but it is asynchronous, and I suspect a second fetch could get kicked off before you processed the first fetch completely (or at all).

Comment: You are absolutely right. I played with fetchMaxBytes and found that relative to this value I fetch 40-100 messages. And then it pauses. So technically it works. Works bad, but works. Thanks!